# NGRX store.dispatch() sync/async calls in a loop

Tags: angular, redux, store, ngrx

I have implemented a Ngrx store in an already working application but I am getting some unexpected behavior with which I would love to get some feedback. To be More precise this is the part that really baffles me.

**action.ts:**

```
export class AddGeoReports implements Action {
    readonly type = ADD_GEOREPORTS_MAP;
    constructor( public payload: { key: string, data: reportPreviewObj[] }) { }
}
```

**reducer.ts**

```
export interface GeoReportsMap {
    data: Map<string, reportPreviewObj[]>
}
const initialState: GeoReportsMap = {
data: new Map()
} 

export function reducer(state = initialState, action: fromActions.GeoReportsMapAction): GeoReportsMap {

        switch(action.type) {
            case fromActions.ADD_GEOREPORTS_MAP: {
                const newState = state.data;
                newState.set(action.payload.key, action.payload.data)

                console.log(newState);
                return {...state, data: newState }
            }

            default: return state
        }
};
```

**service.ts**

```
createGeoReportMapping(geoMappingKey: string , reportPreviewObj: reportPreviewObj){

    let geoReport: reportPreviewObj[] = this.geoReportsMap.get(geoMappingKey);


    if (!geoReport) {
        ...
    } else {
        ...
    }

    this.store.dispatch<fromStore.GeoReportsMapAction>(new fromStore.AddGeoReports({key: geoMappingKey, data: geoReport}));
    }
```

**component.ts**

```
subscribe(reportsObjects => {
    if (reportsObjects.data) {

      this.reportsObjects = reportsObjects.data;
      this.reportsObjects.forEach((reportObject) => {

        if (!Array.isArray(reportObject.data) && (reportObject.data.inspectionInfo.coordinates) && (reportObject.data.inspectionInfo.orderStatusShortname !== 'CLOSED')) {

          let reportPreviewObj: reportPreviewObj = {
                  ...
          };

          if (reportObject.data.documentationView) {
            ...
          }


          const geoMappingKey = `${parseFloat(reportObject.data.inspectionInfo.coordinates.lat.toFixed(7))}, ${parseFloat(reportObject.data.inspectionInfo.coordinates.lng.toFixed(7))}`
          this.mapService.createGeoReportMapping(geoMappingKey, reportPreviewObj);
        }
      });
```

Now after the execution in the service I would expect that every time this function is being called from the component there will be a dispatch event which I will be able to see in the reducer console.log(), instead what I am getting is that the function is called 30 times (if I have 30 reports) and only then it proceeds to enter the reducer and stay there for the next 30 rounds until the map is filled. In essence it appears to store/save somehow the dispatch calls to the store and executes them once the function is done with all the reports. In addition it goes through the reducer calls once it enters there really slow as if they are all somehow async calls.

Any help will be appreciated ! Thanks !

Using: 
"@ngrx/store": "^5.2.0",
"@angular/core": "^5.2.0",

Comment: can we see the code of the component and how you call the service from it ?

Comment: @ylerjen I have edited the post, to show the component itself. But it is just a http request that gets an array of a number of reports. Thanks